# nest Ajax.Beginform inside Html.Beginform

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have beginform and accordeons inside.

It looks like this:

[image]

There may be more than 1 education, working experience etc.

My view looks like this:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "CV", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="main">
            <div class="accordion">
                <div class="accordion-section private-information">
                    <a class="accordion-section-title main-color" href="#accordion-1">Private Information</a>
                    <div class="arrow-down"></div>
                    <div id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content">
                        <div class="private-information-divs">
                            <div class="pcontent-left main-color">name, surname</div>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.privateInformation.Name, new { @class = "pcontent-right main-color" })
                        </div>
.................
                    </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
                </div><!--end .accordion-section-->


                <div class="accordion-section">
                    <a class="accordion-section-title main-color" href="#accordion-2">Education</a>
                    <div class="arrow-down"></div>
                    <div id="accordion-2" class="accordion-section-content">

                        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("EducationTable", new AjaxOptions()
                        {
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            UpdateTargetId = "tblEducation"
                        }))
                        {
                            <div class="private-information-divs">
                                <div class="pcontent-left main-color">University</div>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.newEducation.UniversityName, new { @class = "pcontent-right main-color" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.newEducation.UniversityName)
                            </div>
                            .................

                            <div class="add-education">
                                <button type="submit" class="add-education-button">add</button>
                            </div>
                        }

                        <div id="tblEducation">
                            @Html.Partial("EducationTable")
                        </div>
                    </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
                </div><!--end .accordion-section-->



            <input type="submit" class="continue" value="Continue" />
        </div>
    }
```

And my problem is nested **forms**. As I found in google I can't nest forms (*Ajax.Beginform* inside *Html.Beginform*). But I need that as I'm building my model. My controller is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EducationTable(CV cv)
    {

        CV _cv = new CV();

        if (Session["makeCV"] != null)
            _cv = Session["makeCV"] as CV;
        _cv.education = _cv.education ?? new List<Education>();
        _cv.education.Add(new Education()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            UniversityName = cv.newEducation.UniversityName,
            Faculty = cv.newEducation.Faculty,
            Specialization = cv.newEducation.Specialization,
            StartDate = cv.newEducation.StartDate,
            EndDate = cv.newEducation.EndDate,
            OnGoing = cv.newEducation.OnGoing
        });
        Session["makeCV"] = _cv;

        return PartialView("EducationTable", _cv);
    }
```

etc. and in Index action i'm collecting whole model

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(CV model)
    {
        CV _cv = new CV();

        if (Session["makeCV"] != null)
            _cv = Session["makeCV"] as CV;
        .....
        return View();
    }
```

But When I'm clicking to submit button inside education form (which is Ajax.Beginform) it submits whole form (Html.Beginform) and goes in index action. 
How can I solve that problem? I need to go through these partial views and then submit whole form

Comment: Remove the `Ajax.BeginForm()` and just use the `jQuery.ajax()` methos instead

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you give me an example?

Comment: Sorry, there is too much else in your code which is not making sense (in particular your use of `Session`) and its not clear what your really trying to do. Perhaps [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Yy78S3) might help at least understand how to use jquery ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Search",new AjaxOptions
{
  HttpMethod = "Post",    
  OnSuccess = "Loaded"    
}))
{
   <input type="text" name="q" />
   <button type="submit" value="Search">Search</button>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
   function Loaded(result) {
      alert('result ' + result.Name);
   }
</script>
```

//controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string q)
{

}
```

Comment: can't get it. when i click to submit button it goes in **html.beginform** submit and not to **ajax.beginform**. What's difference between my and your code? you simply trigger alert after form submits

Comment: in mine case it is going to ajax form this is the differnce .please check have you placed your button under right section

Comment: @stylishCoder, This will not work. Nested forms are invalid html and not supported.